# how to show value in front-end user view from php classes to html div

Tags: php, html

I want to show all products by category wise. But data in is not getting properly in front-end view but when i show the classes print_r($product2); it works great in view-source mode.

**I want the data to display in user view mode for example: 
now data is coming like below :**

```
Array( [0] => Array (
            [3] => Array( [id] => 3
                    [name] => Mobile Phones
                    [product] => Array(
                            [26] => Array(
                                    [id] => 26
                                    [image] => uploads/9813ba5bc5.jpg
                                    [pro_name] => iPhone 7
                                    [cat_name] => Mobile Phones
                                    [br_name] => iPhone
                                    [body] => <p>this is iPhone7</p>
                                    [price] => 70000
                                )
                            [25] => Array(
                                    [id] => 25
                                    [image] => uploads/72aca3c29b.jpg
                                    [pro_name] => iPhone 6
                                    [cat_name] => Mobile Phones
                                    [br_name] => iPhone
                                    [body] => <p>this is iPhone6</p>
                                    [price] => 60000
                                )                           
                        )
                )
        )

    [1] => Array(
            [5] => Array([id] => 5
                    [name] => Software
                    [product] => Array(
                            [21] => Array(
                                    [id] => 21
                                    [image] => uploads/7a683e5f82.jpg
                                    [pro_name] => Lorem Ipsum is simply
                                    [cat_name] => Software
                                    [br_name] => Nokia
                                    [body] => <p>this is Nokia</p>
                                    [price] => 5000
                                )
                            [11] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 11
                                    [image] => uploads/05104164e5.jpg
                                    [pro_name] => Lorem Ipsum is simply
                                    [cat_name] => Software
                                    [br_name] => Lenovo
                                    [body] => <p><span>this is  Lenovo/span></p>
                                    [price] => 10000
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
[2] => Array( [4] => Array([id] => 4
                    [name] => Accessories
                    [product] => Array(
                            [20] => Array(
                                    [id] => 20
                                    [image] => uploads/5a113bf1d0.jpg
                                    [pro_name] => japan
                                    [cat_name] => Accessories
                                    [br_name] => iPhone
                                    [body] => this is  Lenovo 4
                                    [price] => 40000
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
```

**but i want like this:**

```
 3
Mobile Phones
   26
   uploads/9813ba5bc5.jpg
   iPhone 7
   Mobile Phones
   iPhone
   this is iPhone7
   70000


   25
   uploads/72aca3c29b.jpg
   iPhone 6
   Mobile Phones
   iPhone
   this is iPhone6
   60000


5
Software
   21
   uploads/7a683e5f82.jpg
   Lorem Ipsum is simply
   Software
   Nokia
   this is Nokia
   5000

   11
   uploads/05104164e5.jpg
   Lorem Ipsum is simply
   Software
   Lenovo
   this is  Lenovo
   10000


4
Accessories
   20
   uploads/5a113bf1d0.jpg
   japan
   Accessories
   iPhone
   this is  Lenovo 4
   40000
```

**my code in classes : Product.php**

```
public function getAllProduct(){
    $query = "SELECT p.*, c.cat_name, b.brand_name
              FROM product as p, category as c, brand as b
              WHERE p.cat_id = c.cat_id AND p.brand_id= b.brand_id 
              ORDER BY p.product_id DESC";

    $data = $this->db->select($query);
    $result = $data->fetch_all();
    $product = array();
    $product1  = array();
    foreach($result as $row) {
        $product[$row[2]] = array(
            'id' => $row[2],
            'name' => $row[8]
        );
        $product1[$row[2]][$row[0]] = array(
            'id' => $row[0],
            'image' => $row[6],
            'pro_name' => $row[1],
            'cat_name' => $row[8],
            'br_name' => $row[9],
            'body' => $row[4],
            'price' => $row[5]
        );
    }
    $product2 =array();
    foreach($product as $id=> $val ) {
        $tmp = array(
            $id => array(
                'id' => $val['id'],
                'name' => $val['name'],
                'product' => $product1[$id],
        ));
        array_push($product2, $tmp);
    }
    return $product2;
}
```

**And my html front-end code is : I think there is something wrong ! How to create foreach loop**

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="content_top">
     <?php
        $result = $product->getAllProduct();
         if($result){
        ?>
    <div class="heading">
        <h3>Latest from <?php echo $result['cat_name'];?></h3>
    </div>
</div>
        <div class="section group">
            <div>
                <img src="admin/<?php echo $result['image']?>" />
                <h2><?php echo $result['product_name']?></h2>
                <p><?php echo $result['body']?></p>
                <p><?php echo $result['price']?></p>
            </div> 
        </div>  
            <?php }?>
</div>
```

Comment: waht happens, when you var_dump/ var_export your result in the HTML section? what data do you get?

Comment: meening, you can see your result, and how to work with it in the html like this : <?php echo '<pre>' . var_export($result, true) . '</pre>'; ?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not really clear, but if you just want to foreach the array resulting from the getAllProduct() function, here is it:

```
    $result = $product->getAllProduct();
if($result){        
    foreach ($result as $product) {
        echo $product['product_name'];
    }       
}
```